# Перенос данных между разными серверами SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день! У меня есть одинаковые по структуре и наполнению два сервера SQL. На каждом из них есть по одинаковой базе 'base', в каждой из которых присутствуют одинаковые таблицы 'table'. Только на втором сервере таблица пустая, и туда надо перенести данные с первого. Экспорт/Импорт и Линкед сервер недоступны из-за ограничений в правах. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно осуществить при таких условиях перенос данных?

Comment: Планируется один перенос?

Comment: Да, это разовая необходимость.

Comment: Сделайте бэкап первой базы, подкиньте на второй сервак и поднимите БД с похожим именем в том же инстансе.

Comment: Тут не всё так просто, структуры баз различаются, и тупо бэкап/рестор сделать не получится. Это я для упрощения восприятия описал тепличные условия. На самом деле перенести надо даже не таблицу целиком, а данные в определённом диапазоне дат. Просто как этот диапазон выбрать и вставить в таблицу на другом сервере я знаю, а вот как взаимодействие между серверами настроить ?

Comment: я посоветовал вам не бэкап рестор, а поднять базу первого сервера на инстансе второго, далее берем данные из первой БД и льем по условию во вторую БД, все это происходит в рамках одного инстанса.

Comment: К сожалению иного доступа к обоим серверам, кроме как через менеджмент студио, у меня нет( То есть бэкап перенести я не смогу.

Comment: много данных то? нагенерите текстовых `insert` команд, скопируйте и вставьте в SSMS

Comment: или через экспорт/импорт в эксель, или XML

Comment: да даже и без файлов, в импорте экспорте сервера указывайте да и все. и пишите запрос на выборку нужных данных.

Comment: Не могу через импорт/экспорт. Как писал выше, видимо в правах ограничен. Там импорт данных вроде как завершается успешно, без ошибок. И количество перенесённых строк указывает верное, но при проверке селектом этих данных на новом сервере не вижу. Получается такая имитация импорта)

Comment: @CutisJackson не может быть такого. Если написало ОК без ошибок то данные должны быть вставлены. Документация говорит, что для импорта экспорт не нужны никакие права кроме select и insert в используемых таблицах.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте мастер импорта и экспорта данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- укажите источник данных (первый сервер)
- укажите точку назначения - второй сервер.
- напишите текст запроса, для выборки исходных данных
- настройте выберите таблицу назначения на втором сервере
- настройте соответствие столбцов и их типы
- запустите пакет

---

вариант второй трешевый, но в целом рабочий.
допустим есть таблица `data (field1 int, field varchar)` и надо ее перенести, то можно написать запрос вида

```
SELECT 'insert into data values (' +
     cast(field1 as varchar) + ' , ''' + field2 + ''');' as sql
FROM data 
WHERE ...
```

выполнить, скопировать нагенерированные SQL запросы (либо `results to -> results to file`) и выполнить набор скриптов (файл) на втором сервере.

*я подобным образом иногда простые данные из экселя переношу, т.к. это быстрее чем кликать в шаги мастера импорта. Тут впрочем тоже можно результат скопировать в эксель, там сформировать строки insert-запросов, и их выполнить.*

Comment: "Экспорт/Импорт и Линкед сервер недоступны из-за ограничений в правах. " (с)

Comment: @NickProskuryakov для  импорта кроме select-insert прав и не надо никаких, вроде.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov еще вариант дописал.

Comment: думаю, он подойдет, хотя конечно жаль автора, можно решить проблему много проще имея права.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov а, что-то не посмотрел, думал это вы автор :) про импорт-экспорт что-то пропустил в вопросе, про линкед сервер то видел.

Comment: Эмм.. второй вариант наверно слишком трешовый. У меня около 30 таблиц, в каждой по 20 примерно заголовков столбцов.. Это же руки просто отвалятся...)

Comment: Я пробовал выгружать в .csv и потом делать импорт из него через select *
into Securities
from openrowset('MSDASQL'
               ,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
               ,'select * from C:\Securities.csv')  Но этот компонент тоже отключен(  SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server.

Comment: Возможно есть иные способы импортировать данные из файла?

Comment: @CutisJackson не ломайте голову, сходите к тому, кто раздает права, и решите вопрос.

Comment: У меня такая ситуация в конторе, что права не дадут, и как сделать не скажут) полный всепроникающий взаимный саботаж во всех подразделениях. Как полагается, с натянутой улыбочкой и разговорами о корпоративной культуре))

Comment: @CutisJackson разбирайтесь с импортом, должен он работать без всяких доп.привилегий

Comment: Хорошо, попробую разрулить) Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В Management Studio ПКМ по пункту Databases >> SQL Assistant >> Script Data.
Отмечаете какие данные нужно перенести, настраиваете Export Options и получаете нужные скрипты:

[image: Таблицы]

[image: Настройки]